# Need to horizontally and vertically center align UL in DIV, and vertically center align the list elements which are text and images

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

I am trying to do the following:

1. Vertically and horizontally center a list within a div.
2. Vertically center the list items.  One item is an image, the others are text.

I've looked at a many solutions but can only manage to get the list horizontally centered.  I cannot get the list centered vertically.  And I cannot get the list items centered vertically.

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.nav a').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $anchor = $(this);


    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500);

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.section {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(../images/white.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.navbar {
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.navbar:hover {
  background-color: #787878;
}
.contents {
  top: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-style: none;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.section h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
.section p {
  width: 600px;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
span.reference {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span.reference a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
span.reference a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  /* Allow the centering to work */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="section" id="sectionAbout">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="table">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>ABOUT</li>
          <li><a href="#sectionServices">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#sectionGWA">
              <img src="images/yellow.png" class="img-circle">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#sectionContact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
      <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
      <div class="table">
        <p>
          <bold>this</bold>is some text
          <br>
          <br>this is some more text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- The JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: left` from the `.navbar ul li` rule, then apply the following CSS.

This works with the `vertical-align` property, which only applies to `inline` and `inline-block` elements. So we have to set all of the list items to `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align:center` to center them within the list.

Then to center the nav, we apply a CSS pseudo element to the container and set it to `height: 100%`, `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align: center`

See the demo below to preview this effect.

```css
div.navbar div.table::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.nav {
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.nav a').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $anchor = $(this);


    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500);

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
div.navbar div.table::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.nav {
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.section {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(../images/white.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.navbar {
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.navbar:hover {
  background-color: #787878;
}
.contents {
  top: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-style: none;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.section h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
.section p {
  width: 600px;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar ul li {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
span.reference {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span.reference a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
span.reference a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  /* Allow the centering to work */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="section" id="sectionAbout">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="table">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>ABOUT</li>
          <li><a href="#sectionServices">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#sectionGWA">
              <img src="images/yellow.png" class="img-circle">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#sectionContact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
      <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
      <div class="table">
        <p>
          <bold>this</bold>is some text
          <br>
          <br>this is some more text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- The JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is great for vertically centering items within divs. This article has a few other scenarios that you might find useful -> [Centering Items](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); /* IE=9*/
}
```